# Error: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm quite new to keras and deep learning. I wanted to use a custom loss function as loss function for my neural network but when i use it I get the following error: OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.

this is the function:

```
def task_based_loss1 (y_true, y_pred):
  e = 2
  s = 50
  loss = s*max(0, y_pred - y_true) + e*max(0, y_true - y_pred) + (y_pred - y_true)**2
  return loss
```

I'm quite sure that the error is in the way i wrote it. Can someone help me please?
Thank you

edit: this is the full error

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-222-69cf216e168c> in <module>()
      6             # callbacks=[callback],
      7             verbose = verbose,
----> 8             epochs = epochs)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-221-cf6b0f250262>:4 task_based_loss1  *
        loss = s*max(0, y_pred - y_true) + e*max(0, y_true - y_pred) + tf.square(y_pred - y_true)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:885 __bool__  **
        self._disallow_bool_casting()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:489 _disallow_bool_casting
        "using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:476 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        " indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.".format(task))

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Comment: Exactly which line gives you the error?

Comment: the error raises when I try to fit the model:
model.compile(loss=task_based_loss1,
                optimizer='adam')

model.fit([train_xw[192:], train_xl],train_yl,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            verbose = verbose,
            epochs = epochs)

Comment: You can't use `max` (built-in python function) on tensors. Use `tf.reduce_max` instead.

Comment: thanks so much @xdurch0 but now it gives me another error :  TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'reduction_indices' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64